# Image displayed in modal shows previously selected image briefly before loading new image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, sveltekit

I'm getting an issue where a custom Modal component that uses a `dialog` element is displaying the previously selected image very briefly before displaying the newly selected one.

I've reproduced it in this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/125f22e7a7d644a1af3eb732337472ac?version=3.58.0). This is a very exaggerated example, the full images in the REPL are ~10MB where as the thumbnails in my local project are ~50KB and the full images 500KB to 1MB. But you'll notice if you click on one, close out of the modal, then click on another the previously selected image is displayed for about a second.

I can fix this issue by preloading the full images (in `svelte:head`) but I feel like it's better design to download the image on click rather than have multiple 500KB images downloaded straight away.

I've tried deleting the content in the modal as it closes with HTMLElement.remove() and playing around with transition delays but got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting `selectedImage` when closing the modal would prevent the previous image from being shown

```
    let selectedImage = '';
    let showModal = false;
    
    $: if(!showModal) selectedImage = ''
```

(The relevant code should be included in the question, not just the Repl)